# vue reactivity issue with :disabled

Tags: vue.js

I have a button with a computed bounded isDisabled method

```
<button :disabled="isDisabled"
        @click="saveMember"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Invite
</button>

computed: {
  isDisabled() {
    return !this.emailValid || this.savingUser
  }
}
```

Then I have a method which updates the emailValid field.

```
methods: {
  validateEmail() {
    .......
    this.emailValid = true
```

When I am tracing the condition it gives me false

```
{{ !emailValid || savingUser  }} //false
```

But my button is still disabled.

I have tried to add a key

```
<button :disabled="isDisabled"
    @click="saveMember"
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary mr-1"
    :key="`${this.member.email}`">Invite
</button>
```

But still doesn't work.

Comment: `console.log('isDisabled',this.emailValid,this.savingUser,!this.emailValid || this.savingUser)` (or similar) in `inDisabled` should help you pin this down

Comment: also ``:key="`${this.member.email}`"`` could be done simpler by `:key="member.email"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the `this` keyword in template tags.

Try

```
{{ !emailValid || savingUser  }}
```

Edit: also, is `saveMember` a method? You should call it like `saveMember()` in your `@click` listener.